# How to get a picture from the photo library with PhoneGap on iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, cordova-3

I'm using the following code to try to select a photo from the iOS photo library:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(this.onCaptureSuccess, this.onCaptureFail, {
    allowEdit: true,
    correctOrientation: true,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    soureType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    targetHeight: 315,
    targetWidth: 320
});
```

I'm using iOS 7 (7.0.4) on an iPhone 5s and PhoneGap 3.3.0. No matter what I do it always brings the camera up.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using phonegap build or the local client?

Comment: Local client.  I'm running 'phonegap build ios' in Terminal and then hitting 'Run' in Xcode to run it on my phone.

Comment: Did you install the camera plugin as well?

Comment: Yep.  I can take pictures just fine.  I just can't get it to allow me to select from existing photos.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Think I found it:

```
soureType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
```

should be:

```
sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
```

sourceType has a typo in it. Maybe thats it?

Comment: I'm going to have to wait until I get home to check this.  If that's the problem I'm going to nominate myself for the "OhMyGodICantBelieveIDidThat" award.

Comment: Enjoy your well-earned bounty when StackOverflow lets me deliver it in 4 hours. :)

Answer (score -2):

Below code is for access gallery photos:

```
 Camera.sourceType = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY 

 or

 Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
```

then a photo chooser dialog is shown, from which a photo from the album can be selected.

Comment: That doesn't work either. How is that different from setting the sourceType in the cameraOptions param of getPicture()?